The defining equations of the projective completion.
Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{A}_0^n$ be an affine variety, where $\mathbb{A}_0^n$ denotes the affine piece of $\mathbb{P}^n$ with $x_0\neq 0$. We have the following fact for the projective completion $\bar{U}$ (which is defined to be the Zariski closure of $U$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$):
Fact:
Suppose $\mathbb{I}_a(U)=\{ f_i|i\in \Gamma\}$, then:
$$ \bar{U}=\mathbb{V}(f_i^h|i\in \Gamma)$$
where $f_i^h\in k[x_0,\dots,x_n]$ denotes the homogenization of $f_i$.
My question is: Can we give a counterexample such that:
$$ U=\mathbb{V}_a( f_1,\dots,f_m)\not\Rightarrow \bar{U}=\mathbb{V}(f_1^h,\dots, f_m^h)$$
It seems that the problems will arise when $\left\langle f_1,\dots,f_m\right\rangle$ is not a radical ideal, but I haven't find any counterexamples yet.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

This is an example from Gathmann's algebraic geometry notes:
Consider the ideal $J = \left\langle x,y-x^2\right\rangle \subset K[x,y]$ with the affine zero locus $X=\mathbb{V}_a(J)= \left\lbrace 0 \right\rbrace \subset \mathbb{A}^2$. This one-point set is also closed in $\mathbb{P}^2$, thus $\overline{X}=\left\lbrace (0:0:1)\right\rbrace$. But homogenizing two given generators gives the homogenous ideal $\left\langle x,zy-x^2\right\rangle$, the projective zero locus is then $\left\lbrace (0:1:0),(0:0:1)\right\rbrace \supsetneq\overline{X}$.

Thank you! (Why did I miss this one? :(    )
